# AWS elasticsearch service returning 403 response with .NET HttpClient - wrong casing in http request headers

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, http-headers, amazon-elasticsearch

Anyone ever had issues with casing in headers and AWS elasticsearch service? Trying to call `_cat/health`, but the service returns 403. `Connection: Close` doesn't work, `Connection: close` works. This is annoying in .NET Framework where the casing is forced.

We're using elasticsearch 5.6 in AWS elasticsearch service.

Example of a call that doesn't work (in postman):

```
Accept: application/json
Connection: Close
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-Amz-Date: 20181130T075307Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, SignedHeaders=accept;cache-control;connection;host;postman-token;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.4.0
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Example of a call that works:

```
Accept: application/json
Connection: close
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-Amz-Date: 20181130T075307Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, SignedHeaders=accept;cache-control;connection;host;postman-token;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.4.0
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Is AWS really that strict when it comes to headers? Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: [Per RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6.1), `close` in lowercase is the correct value. Funnily, though, header names are case-insensitive, so `connection: close` would work as well.

Comment: header names are not case sensitive according RFC2616 and header values depends on application so may be aws is strict about that but i'm not sure

Comment: @varnit RFC 2616 has been obsoleted by RFC 7230 :-)

Comment: thankyou @val i did not know

Comment: @varnit Not a big deal as both specs say the same thing regarding the problem at hand.

Comment: yes that's true